# How can I increase the drop rate for Antlion Mandibles

Tags: terraria-mobile

I am trying to get the sandgun in Terraria, and it's impossible for me to get any mandibles after killing antlions! Is there a specific pre-hardmode weapon that increases chances of getting mandibles? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no weapon that will increase the drop chance of mandibles, or anything else for that matter.

Antlions and Albino Antlions (mobile/console) have a 1 in 7 chance of dropping a mandible. Antlion Chargers and Antlion Swarmers (both desktop only) have an increased chance of 1 in 3.

What you can do to increase your chance is increase the spawn rate of enemies, this will give you more Antlions to kill and thus increase your chances of getting the drop you want. Use battle potions and water candles to easily increase the spawn rate.

Comment: Remember this is mobile edition, which does not have chargers or swarmers.

Comment: @angussidney good point,